# Thunderbird: show space usage by sender

Tags: email, thunderbird, disk-space

Is it possible to obtain a (disk) space usage view, like in WinDirStat in Windows or baobab in Linux, for my emails? Specifically, split by sender?

If not, is it maybe possible to get a simple readout in descending order like this:

```
ADDRESS            SPACE_USAGE
email_address_1    5%
email_address_2    3.2%
email_address_3    3.1%
```

and so on, for all the mail?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this has it, but you might try https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/mail-summaries/   IT analyzes email content on several factors.

Comment: "Works with Thunderbird 68.0 - 73.0"

Answer (score 0):

I see there is https://github.com/devmount/third-stats actively maintained